# linux command line :file names that contain a number & replace string

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, operating-system, kernel

so i am new to linux 
and I was wondering how do i do the following

1-list all names of file that contain a number
[I know

```
  $ls *[0-9]*
```

but it wont work if i have a file that starts with a number

2-Also replace any "an" in file names in the output with "xx" print on screen and store it in a file

I reached

```
ls | tr -u  "an" xx >modified.txt
```

problem is that it changes a to x and n to x ...but i want an together not separately

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

List all names of file that contain a number
Your example works fine for me for files that start with a number, so you might want to clarify what sort of Linux system you're on, or which shell or language you're using.

```
# In sh/bash:
ls *[0-9]*
# with perl:
perl -e '@globbed_files = <*[0-9]*>; print "@globbed_files\n"'
# With find (filters out directories):
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*[0-9]*' -type f
```

Replace any "an" in file names in the output with "xx" print on screen and store it in a file

```
ls | sed 's/an/xx/g' | tee file.out
```